# Java passing a (lambda) function with two arguments

Tags: java, function, parameters

I'm trying to implement a function to read files, but I cannot change the signature of the method. There are a lot of cross references in the code but maybe someone can enlighten me, I have been stuck for 3 days right now. This is for a school assignment.

The first method I'm trying to pass into the function is the following:

```
public static Purchase fromLine(String textLine, List<Product> products) {
        Purchase newPurchase = null;
        String[] purchases = textLine.split(",");
        int foundBarcode = products.indexOf(getProductFromBarcode(products, Long.parseLong(purchases[0])));

        products.indexOf(purchases);
        newPurchase = new Purchase(
                products.get(foundBarcode),
                Integer.parseInt(purchases[1].trim())
        );
```

Somehow I want to pass this function into my import file function.

```
    public static <E> void importItemsFromFile(List<E> items, String filePath, Function<String,E> converter) {
        int originalNumItems = items.size();

        Scanner scanner = createFileScanner(filePath);

        // TODO read all source lines from the scanner,
        //  convert each line to an item of type E and
        //  and add each item to the list

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            // input another line with author information
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            // TODO convert the line to an instance of E
            E newItem = converter.apply(line);

            // TODO add the item to the list of items
            items.add(newItem);
        }
        System.out.printf("Imported %d items from %s.\n", items.size() - originalNumItems, filePath);
    }
```

I hope someone can help me and explain how to pass this function into the other function's converter parameter.
Tried to do a lot of research on this topic but I'm still not able to find the answer. Please help me stackoverflow community!:D

Comment: Does that first method return anything?  I don't see a `return` statement, but in your second method, you're assigning the return value of the first method to `newItem`.  Can you maybe show _all_ of the first method, not just a few lines?

Comment: We also need to see what the data looks like.  You'll get better answers if you read the SO help on how to ask a question.  People can't do much if they need to guess the problem you're trying to solve.  Also note the requirement to state when you're asking for help with homework.

Comment: So you have a file that has information about purchases, and the first code snippet converts a line of that file into a `Purchase`, and you want to pass that first code snippet into `importItemsFromFile`, so that the entire file's contents get put into a `List<Purchase>`. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Gene Thanks, I will read the SO help and added the statement that this is actually an homework assignment.

Comment: @Sweeper That's my problem indeed, but I'm stuck on the function call of the `importItemsFromFile` because I have no clue how to pass the first function's fourth parameter (the Function<String, Object> converter

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare this like this first inside a 'super - private function'

```
private Function<String, Purchase> doSomething() {
     return textLine -> {
        Purchase newPurchase = null;
        String[] purchases = textLine.split(",");
        int foundBarcode = products.indexOf(getProductFromBarcode(products, Long.parseLong(purchases[0])));

        products.indexOf(purchases);
        return new Purchase(products.get(foundBarcode), Integer.parseInt(purchases[1].trim())
     };
}
```

Then before calling this importItemsFromFile() method, you declare this function as a `variable`

```
Function<String, Purchase> abcFunction = doSomething();
```

and then call this importItemsFromFile() function like this

```
importItemsFromFile(items, filePath, abcFunction);
```

The reason why this works is, lambda operator returns a Functional Interface, here it is "Function", if you pass 3 arguments, you will need a `BiFunction<T, U, R>` for that.

Thats why these FunctionalInterfaces are sometimes called super private functions, as they are used inside another function.

And Hey give me extra points for this, as I even completed your half written function, and saved your 3 days time.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little lost by the top snippet, but all you need to do is define an implementation of the [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) interface.  You can do this simply by defining a class that implements the interface or you can specify a lambda that would do the same thing.

Assuming the top code block is what you want in your lambda you would do something like this,

```
(textLine) ->{
        String[] purchases = textLine.split(",");
        int foundBarcode = products.indexOf(getProductFromBarcode(
            products, Long.parseLong(purchases[0])));
        products.indexOf(purchases);
        return new Purchase(
                products.get(foundBarcode),
                Integer.parseInt(purchases[1].trim())
        )
```